# Random Number Algorithm - Implementation in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

Can anyone please suggest me a random number algorithm that I can use for implementation in java? I don't want to use the Math.random() function.

Note: I want to write my own random number generation function in java; therefore for I am looking for an algorithm that I can use.

Comment: Are you looking for [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) ?

Comment: [Generating random numbers in a range with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/363681)

Comment: *Why* don't you want to use `Math.random()`?

Comment: You will need to seed system time... [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis())

Comment: Check out this question for more suggestions: [SO: How to generate a random number from scratch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967491/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-scratch)

Comment: @kdgregory I want to write my own random number generation function in java; therefore for I am looking for an algorithm that I can use.

Comment: What are your requirements? Sheesh.

Comment: That does not answer kdgregory's question...

Comment: @vas - I asked because the reason will determine what sort of answer is appropriate. For example: you need crytographically-secure randomness. If you just want to reinvent the wheel, then Google turns up lots (2MM+) of results. And since you have no real requirements, you could have picked one arbitrarily.

Comment: @kdgregory thanks for your suggestions; i will try google search for some algos for my research.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question actually language-agnostic, and shouldn't be specifically java. Also, I think it's very easy to find information on things like this. Look at the wiki pages for [Pseudorandom number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_number_generator) and [Random number generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#Computational_methods). If you're looking for something simple (relatively) look at the [XORshift RNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift)

```c
uint32_t xor128(void) { //A C version from wiki
  static uint32_t x = 123456789;
  static uint32_t y = 362436069;
  static uint32_t z = 521288629;
  static uint32_t w = 88675123;
  uint32_t t;

  t = x ^ (x << 11);
  x = y; y = z; z = w;
  return w = w ^ (w >> 19) ^ (t ^ (t >> 8));
}
```

Or in Java:

```
public class IsNotFour {
    int x = 123456789;
    int y = 362436069;
    int z = 521288629;
    int w = 88675123;

    int xor128() { // A converted C version from wiki
        int t = x ^ (x << 11);
        x = y;
        y = z;
        z = w;
        w = w ^ (w >>> 19) ^ (t ^ (t >>> 8));
        return w; 
    }
}
```

Note that `x`, `y`, `z` and `w` together make the seed.

Comment: You're right, who needs complicated strange bit shifty functions when you could just use [xkcd's?](http://xkcd.com/221/) It's much more random.

Comment: Just joking, as I did not see a specific seed. Are the first outputs `DCA345EA, 1B5116E6, 951049AA, D88D00B0`?

Comment: Yes, I got that too. The values for x, y, z, and w are actually the seeds, so those can be tweaked.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that, I've added Java code as using `>>>` instead of `>>` is a bit tricky.